# Cannot start the Google Cloud SQL Proxy on RPi 3

Tags: linux, mysql

I am trying to install Google Cloud SQL Proxy to my RPi 3, but it does not work after install the LINUX-64BIT proxy and the below command on this page [Connecting mysql Client Using the Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy)

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql &
```

after the command, it said:

> bash: .cloud_sql_proxy: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

and I checked the file, saying that:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV, statically linked, not stripped
```

Please advise what I can do to solve this.